# Power capacitor needed with high current LED

Tags: led, capacitor, mosfet

I'm designing a pcb which, among other things, with control several high current LED panels. These panels have the proper circuitry in them, so all I do, is give them 12v.

The maximum current one will draw, is 30A. I'm using a thick PCB with bus-bars. I am controlling the panels with a low side power mosfet. I am using a microcontroller for the logic, on the same power supply, dropped down to 5v.

My question is, do these panels need a power capacitor to avoid having the power rail saturated and reseting my mcu when they are immediately turned on? If so, is there a ballpark of what sizes should be used?

I have done pcb's with stepper motors and servos, and without a cap for each, they would reset the mcu. I used around a 470uF cap and it worked. I couldn't find anything online about the characteristics of LEDs and if they need caps like servos and the like.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LED panel doesn't need a capacitor.  Your MCU does.

In fact, adding capacitance to the LED panel will make the inrush surge of the LED panel *worse*, not better, because the first thing that happens is that the capacitor must charge from zero to 12V.

Generally, a slight drop in the 12V rail due to an applied load will have no effect on a 5V rail regulated down from it.  You should use a proper voltage-regulator device with the appropriate power and bypass capacitors applied around it, as specified in the datasheet.

You should *also* use a high-frequency bypass capacitor across the MCU's power terminals, and this will also be suggested in *its* datasheet.  You may wish to add a more substantial power capacitor across the MCU as well, if you like the belt-and-braces approach.

When it comes to the differences between LEDs and motors, LEDs are an essentially resistive load, while motors are essentially inductive.  When a motor load is switched *off* it tends to generate a voltage pulse, due to attempting to pull the same current through a suddenly infinite-impedance supply.  By adding a capacitor to your motor load, you were compensating for their inherent inductiveness; you could have achieved a similar result using freewheel diodes instead.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Though, it wouldn't have to charge the cap each time since it's a low side driver. The cap would stay charged until the panel was first turned on. That was my thinking for it

Comment: If the capacitor is on the near side of the driver, then it'll be charged when the power initially comes up, probably before the MCU finishes booting.  If it's on the far side, then it'll be discharged through the LEDs when the driver is switched off.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If I wire it like this: http://tinyurl.com/ydy44wxd  where the logic control is the MCU, then when power is applied initially, it will be charged, like you said. Then it can use that power to control the spike. Isn't that a good outcome?

Comment: Right, in that position I'd say it's "before" the driver, since the two grounds are implicitly connected.  That means it's effectively stabilising the 12V rail on the high side of the regulator, which is fine - but it's more important to stabilise the low side for the MCU's benefit.

Comment: Got it. So to clarify: only need power caps if the load is inductive, not resistive. If I'm using a dc servo or linear actuator, that's still inductive, even if the shaft isn't spinning fast? It's just the coils that make it inductive?

Comment: Yes, coils are inherently inductive.  Long wires or loops of cable can be, too.  It's all about electromagnetic coupling.